# jquery ajax post - not being fired first time

Tags: ajax, jquery, http-post

I'm trying to do an ajax post after a button is clicked, and it works in firefox but not in IE the first time the page is loaded. It does work if I refresh the page and try again second time - but not first time and this is crucial.

I've scanned over various web pages - could it be anything to do with the listener? (I've just seen this mentioned mentiond somewhere) Is there something not set correctly to do with ajax and posting when page first loads?

```
$(document).ready(function() {                      
$('#btnCont').bind('click',function () {    

var itm = $("#txtItm").val();
var qty = $("#txtQty").val();
var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();
var op_id = $("#txtOp_id").val();

 //if i alert these values out they alert out no prob
 alert(itm+'-'+qty+'-'+msg+'-'+op_id);


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "do_request.php?msg="+msg+"&itm="+itm+"&qty="+qty+"&op_id="+op_id,
success: function (msg) {
    document.getElementById('div_main').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div_success').style.display='block';
    var row_id = document.getElementById('txtRow').value;
    document.getElementById('row'+row_id).style.backgroundColor='#b4e8aa';
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error submitting request.');
}
});
```

});

Comment: For error, why is XMLHttpRequest the name of your first argument to the function?

Comment: I saw that somewhere and have used it successfully with no problems. Even when I remove it I still have this current problem.

Comment: You wrote that at the first time the ajax call not work on IE. Do you mean that nothing will be posted and you verified it with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or just the POST come not on the server? How and when the variables `msg`, `itm`, `qty` and `op_id` vill de set? Which are the test values at the first time? Could you include more **full code** which produce the error or could you post the url of the page having the problem? It could be also important to have full the HTML code of the page.

Comment: I always use $(function(){ }); to wrap my jQuery load event. You don't need the document bit. And also, if you're using jQuery why do you then use document.getElementById? Makes no sense.

Comment: I've still getting use to jquery so I'll amend the document.getElementById shortly;)

Answer (score 0):

I would start debugging the click event. I.e. if you try to put .bind into a a href tag, the tag itself has a click event that may act on an unwanted way. There exist a command that are named something like event.preventDefaults() that avoids the standard feature of click.  After All, you try to manipulate the DOM last of all actions (document.load).

$('#btnCont').bind('click',function () { .. }

I would also try to debug the same functionality with adding onClientClick to the tag instead of adding bind to the document load.

I hope that bring some light.

Comment: Hi, the click event works every time - it's just the ajax bit that doesn't fire first time.

Comment: Hi Gunner, Yes. I tooked that in mind. This kind of event handling can, on some circumstances (somebody may know exactly why) make the code appear as you pointed the click event to href, while under the hood - the web browser is still pointing to the first assigned handling. I would still prefer onClientClick="anyFunction();" or href="javascript:anyFunction();", but you probably have a reason of your choice.